# Keep Score method for tic tac toe is not updating score variables properly

Tags: ruby

I am currently adding a 'keep score' method to the below tic tac toe game. The method game_score works insofar as it increments after the game, but always resets back to 0.

I think the problem is something very simple, and there are similar questions already answered but I couldn't apply them to my code.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

```
INITIAL_MARKER = ' '
PLAYER_MARKER = 'X'
COMPUTER_MARKER = 'O'
player_score = 0
computer_score = 0

def prompt(msg)
  puts "=>#{msg}"
end  

def display_board(brd)
  system 'clear'
  puts "You're a #{PLAYER_MARKER} Computer is #{COMPUTER_MARKER}"
  puts ""
  puts"     |     |"
  puts"  #{brd[1]}  |  #{brd[2]}  |    #{brd[3]}"
  puts"     |     |"
  puts"-----+-----+-----"
  puts"     |     |"
  puts"  #{brd[4]}  |  #{brd[5]}  |    #{brd[6]}"
  puts"     |     |"
  puts"-----+-----+-----"
  puts"     |     |"
  puts"  #{brd[7]}  |  #{brd[8]}  |    #{brd[9]}"   
  puts"     |     |"
end

def initialize_board
   new_board = {}
   (1..9).each {|num| new_board[num] = INITIAL_MARKER}
   new_board
end

def empty_squares(brd)
  brd.keys.select{|num| brd[num] == INITIAL_MARKER}
end

def player_places_piece!(brd)
  square = INITIAL_MARKER
  loop do
    prompt ("Choose a square (#{empty_squares(brd).join(',')})")
    square = gets.chomp.to_i
    break if empty_squares(brd).include?(square)
     prompt "Sorry, that's not a valid choice."
    end
    brd[square] = PLAYER_MARKER
  end

def computer_places_piece(brd)
  square = empty_squares(brd).sample
  brd[square] = COMPUTER_MARKER
end

def board_full(brd)
  empty_squares(brd).empty?
end

def someone_won?(brd)
  !!detect_winner(brd)
end

def detect_winner(brd)

  #computer_score =
  winning_lines = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] +
                  [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]] +
                  [[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
  winning_lines.each do |line|
    if brd[line[0]] == PLAYER_MARKER && 
       brd[line[1]] == PLAYER_MARKER &&
       brd[line[2]] == PLAYER_MARKER 
        return 'Player'
        player_score += 1

    elsif 
       brd[line[0]] ==  COMPUTER_MARKER && 
       brd[line[1]] == COMPUTER_MARKER &&
       brd[line[2]] == COMPUTER_MARKER 
        return 'Computer'
        computer_score += 1
    else

    end
  end
  nil
end 

def game_score (player_score, computer_score, board)
  player_score += 1 if detect_winner(board) == 'Player'
  computer_score += 1 if detect_winner(board) == 'Computer'
  prompt("Player Score is: #{player_score}")
  prompt("Computer Score is: #{computer_score}")
end


loop do 
  board = initialize_board

  loop do
    display_board(board)

    player_places_piece!(board)
    break if someone_won?(board) || board_full(board)
    display_board(board)

    computer_places_piece(board)
    display_board(board)
    break if someone_won?(board) || board_full(board)
  end

  if someone_won?(board)
    prompt "#{detect_winner(board)} won!"



    #player_score += 1 if detect_winner(board)== 'Player'
    #computer_score += 1 if detect_winner(board)== 'Computer'
    #display("Player Score: #{player_score}")
    #display("Computer Score: #{computer_score}")

  else
    prompt "It's a tie!"
  end

 game_score(player_score, computer_score, board) 
 binding pry
  prompt("would you like to play again?")
  input = gets.chomp
  break unless input == 'y'
end
prompt("bye")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass in `player_score` and `computer_score` into the `game_score` method, then you get new variables that are scoped to that method. They are not the same as your global variables that you declare at the top.
May I suggest that you try to write some classes that encapsulates the proper abstractions (like game, board, score etc). I think that would make it easier to figure out how you should save your state.